# Zabbix parsing macros value

Tags: ssl, monitoring, zabbix

Based on the [Website certificate by Zabbix agent 2](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/ssl), I want to autodetect the purposes of the SSL certificates.

Moreover, without external files, based on macro values, as an example (not necessarily in this form):

**{$macro.example}:**

```json
{
"zabbix.com": {
  "name": "zabbix.com",
  "port": "443",
  "ip": "192.168.1.1"
  },
"google.com": {
  "name": "google.com",
  "port": "443",
  "ip": ""
  }
}
```

or like this:

**{$macro2.example}:**

```
zabbix.com:443:192.168.1.1; google.com:443:
```

Accordingly, there is an idea to parse the value of a variable and select the **name**, **port** and **IP**, but have not yet found how to do this.

Ideally, you can implement it at the script level or place JSON somewhere and parse it, but I would like to implement a more universal scheme.

I looked at the basic types of detection rules, but could not find how to implement this.